# invalid character when running liquibase script

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

When I run the script below in Sql Developer it correctly creates my global temporary table but when I run my liquibase script it fails because of "invalid character". Anyone know why this fails?

**In Sql Developer** (works)

```
 CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

**Liquibase xml** (fails with below stacktrace)

```
<changeSet id="createGlobalTemporaryTableForTransactionsMove" author="me" >
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="TransactionsToMove"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <sql splitStatements="false" endDelimiter=";"><![CDATA[              
      CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
          TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
          ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
    ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    SEVERE 2013-11-14 09:10:liquibase: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:105)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1014)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:998)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:113)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.runChangelog(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:177)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.create(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:145)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.dropAndCreate(DatabaseManager.java:349)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.main(DatabaseManager.java:720)
SEVERE 2013-11-14 09:10:liquibase: Change Set db/scripts/movetohistorical-oracleserver.xml::createGlobalTemporaryTableForTransactionsMove::marbe failed.  Error: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:105)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1014)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:998)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:113)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.runChangelog(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:177)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.create(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:145)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.dropAndCreate(DatabaseManager.java:349)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.main(DatabaseManager.java:720)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
        ... 11 more
INFO 2013-11-14 09:10:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Exception in thread "main" se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManagerException: Liquibase changelog update failed using changelog: db-main-create-13.4.xml, reason: Migration failed for change set db/scripts/movetohistorical-oraclese
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character
:
          Caused By: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character
:
          Caused By: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.runChangelog(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:180)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.create(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:145)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.dropAndCreate(DatabaseManager.java:349)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.DatabaseManager.main(DatabaseManager.java:720)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/scripts/movetohistorical-oracleserver.xml::createGlobalTemporaryTableForTransactionsMove::marbe:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character
:
          Caused By: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character
:
          Caused By: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:347)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:113)
        at se.mypackage.exbo.database.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabaseManager.runChangelog(LiquibaseDatabaseManager.java:177)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TransactionsToMove(
              TransactionId NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (TransactionId))
              ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:105)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1014)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:998)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try dropping the final semicolon

Comment: That did it! Add it as an answer and I will set it as correct, Thx!

Comment: Please add a comment to the downvote so I know what to improve for next time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The semicolon is a command terminator used in client-side applications such as Oracle SQL*Plus.

Is is usually not needed when invoking a db command through a Prepared Statement or a similar technology.

Answer (score 0):

**Clearly: DROP SEMICOLONS from Liquibase**

**Semicolons are not tolerated properly with Liquibase.**
SQL Developer expects you to use semicolons.
Copying-pasting statments from one to the other will get you into trouble.

Some attempts of explaining can be found on the the web e.g:
http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/formatted-sql-enddelimiter-issue

It is worth noticing that Oracle themselves have different approach to semicolons: SQL*Plus commands do not need to be termianted with semicolon; whereas statements are supposed to.